# Convert React events to Webcomponent events

Tags: reactjs, web-component

The React docs provide an example of how to use react inside a webcomponent. But [the example](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/web-components.html#using-react-in-your-web-components) provided is trivial, and not enough to learn from. In particular it does not provide information about how to bubble up an event out of a webcomponent.

Suppose that the code started as

```
const proto = Object.create(HTMLElement.prototype, {
  attachedCallback: {
    value: function() {
      const mountPoint = document.createElement('span');
      this.createShadowRoot().appendChild(mountPoint);

      const name = this.getAttribute('name');
      const url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(name);
      ReactDOM.render(<input onchange={....} value={...}></input>, mountPoint);
    }
  }
});
document.registerElement('x-search', {prototype: proto});
```

How would this be wired up?

Answer (score 0):

What about instead of using [xeact](https://github.com/pengzhanlee/xeact-core)?

Define component:

```
import xeact, {exposed, dispatchEvent, Component} from 'xeact';

@xeact('search')
export default class Search extends Component {

    state = {
        value: '',
    };

    onChange(e) {
        const value = e.target.value;
        this.setState({
            value
        }, () => {
            dispatchEvent(this, 'change' , {
                value
            });
        });
    }

    @exposed
    get value() {
        return this.state.value;
    }

    render() {
        const {value} = this.state;
        return <span>
            <input value={value} onChange={(e) => {this.onChange(e)}} />
        </span>
    }
}
```

Use it from HTML:

```
<x-search></x-search>
<script>
    // get value from `change` event
    document.querySelector('x-search').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
        console.log(e.detail.value);
    });

    // get value from getter
    document.querySelector('x-search').value;
</script>
```